# imagemagick in iphone

Tags: imagemagick

i m using imagemagick in my mac os x version 10.6.4 and all cmd is working well in my os .
but i want to use imagemagick framework in my iphone project i have added imagemagick framework in my xcode but where can I use command in the xcode project for changing the image ...... 
if some body can help me thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can find ImageMagick compiled for use in iPhone projects here: [Latest ImageMagick](http://www.cloudgoessocial.net/2010/05/01/latest-imagemagick/).

You can't use the command line version on the iPhone though, so you'll want to use the [MagickWand API](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use the commands in iphone project to change the image as you do in the cmd. We can use `ConvertImageCommand()` of the ImageMagick to acheive this. You can acheive the same results with this C API. Refer this link to know about the usage of the function.
[ConvertImageCommand Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17216)

Comment: Are you still using this? It looks like the last changes in the iOS repo for ImageMagick are in 3 years ago.