# Can the iPhone/iPad decode Jpeg2000 images client side?

Tags: iphone, ipad, image-processing, decode, jpeg2000

I have done a fair amount of looking around on the internet for an answer to this question, and have little to show for it. I am making an app that will stream medical images over the internet, which will be in Jpeg2000 format, and then I need to decode them on the iOS device for viewing/manipulating.

Is there a library that will allow me to do this on the device? Is this feature natively present? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/jp2.php) should be able to do what you want. I have used ImageMagick before but not in a iOS environment. Check this out for more iOS details [imagemagick in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521005/imagemagick-in-iphone).